# React - How can i add new value to an array and display this array in alert window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a really simple program but I have got a small problem.
When I write a new omen in input label, I want to add this to the array that is in state and display whole content of the array in alert box.
How can I do it in the easiest way?

```js
class Draw extends React.Component {
  state = {
    omen: "",
    omens: ["first", "second", "third"],
    newOmen: "",
  };

  handleRandomOmen = () => {
    const omensArray = this.state.omens;
    const randomOmen =
      omensArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * omensArray.length)];

    this.setState({
      omen: randomOmen,
    });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      newOmen: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleAddOmen = () => {
    const test = this.state.omens.push(this.state.newOmen);
    console.log(test);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <button onClick={this.handleRandomOmen}>Show omen</button>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.newOmen}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddOmen}>Add omen</button>
        <h1>{this.state.omen}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Draw />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you always need to update a state with `setState`,
adding a new array value with `push` will be overriden by the next react cycle.

You can use your the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new array with the old values + your new one:

```js
  handleAddOmen = () => {
    this.setState({
        omens: [
            ...this.state.omens,
            this.state.newOmen
        ]
    });
  };
```